# How to check if file object is random access

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-access

I have a function that accepts an arbitrary file handle and either loads all the data or allows the data to be loaded lazily *if* the object supports random access.

```
class DataLoader:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.headers = {}
    def load_data(self):
        # header is a hashable (e.g. namedtuple with name, size, offset)
        header = self.load_next_header()
        if self.file.random_access:
            # Return and load the data only as necessary if you can
            self.headers[header.name] = (header, None)
            self.file.seek(header.size + self.file.tell())
        else:
            # Load the data up front if you can't
            self.headers[header.name] = (header, self.file.read(header.size))
```

How can I check if a file object supports random access?

Comment: another strategy might be to try to access randomly. if it throws an exception, you know it doesn't support it. See, for reference, https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/asking_for_permission_instead_of_forgiveness_when_working_with_files.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`seekable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seekable) method to check if the file supports random access.

> **seekable()**
>
> Return `True` if the stream supports random access. If `False`, `seek()`, `tell()` and `truncate()` will raise `OSError`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach in line with the Python convention of [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) is to just assume the file object supports random access and handle the exception that occurs when it doesn't:

```
class DataLoader:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.headers = {}
    def load_data(self):
        # header is a hashable (e.g. namedtuple with name, size, offset)
        header = self.load_next_header()
        try:
            # Return and load the data only as necessary if you can
            self.headers[header.name] = (header, None)
            self.file.seek(header.size + self.file.tell())
        except OSError:
            # Load the data up front if you can't
            self.headers[header.name] = (header, self.file.read(header.size))
```

Comment: Thanks. Under normal circumstances I would accept this as the answer. However, for the real application I have in mind, I need to select a different loading method up front based on the seekability.